# 500 Internal Server Error Postman, Flask y MongoDBCompass

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, postman, pymongo

estoy utilizando mongo compass y cuando hago una petición POST e incluso GET (en Postman) me sale ese error "500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR". ¿Alguien sabe a qué se debe? Es la primera vez que ocupo estas herramientas. Gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]